# Jetty+Jersey: are container-managed entity transactions possible?

Tags: jpa, transactions, jersey, jetty, entitymanager

I'm using hibernate/jpa 5.2.10 with Jetty 9.4.

Is it possible to set up Jetty in a way such that:

a) servlet requests (including Jersey) are wrapped in entity transactions, and

b) the required EntityManager is accessible from within Jersey resource classes

?

I don't want to use Spring/DI/IoC and stuff and keep things as simple and fast as possible. Are there other ways to achieve Jersey RESTful development with rapid "RTT"?

Maybe I just implement a static method to create an entity manager and associate it with the current request, and set up a request listener for cleanup, and use that method explicitly inside the Jersey resource methods? Similarly I could to with the EM factory and store that inside webapp context, and use a listener for cleanup. Though, I'd prefer a trodden path, but the existing Java EE seem bent on killing unit testing to some extent.